# How to assign multiple variables by function return value in dash shell

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I use brand new usage of 'bash'.

```
func(){
  echo Dan 38
}
read name age < <(func)
echo "name=$name age=$age"
```

How to convert these into dash? (In fact it is busybox's shell)

I use following lines to replace `read name age < <(func)`

```
func > /tmp/$$
name=`cat /tmp/$$ | awk '{print $1}'`
age=`cat /tmp/$$ | awk '{print $2}'`
rm /tmp/$$
```

But, I'm wonder is there better solution?

Comment: `read` is specified by POSIX ([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/read.html)), so if nothing else, you should at least be able to write `read name age < /tmp/$$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1, C-style

Modify the function to accept the names (you can think of them as pointers) of the variables where the result is to be written.

```
func () { eval "$1=Dan $2=38"; }
func name age
echo "name=$name age=$age"
```

## Solution 2, manual split

This is similar to your solution, but has the advantage that it doesn't use files or call to external programs like awk.

```
func(){ echo Dan 38 }
both=$(func)
name=${both%% *}
age=${both#* }
echo "name=$name age=$age"
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the C-style, I just know eval can simulate C-style pointers. And we can assign multiple variables in one line.